# How to get INT value from Tkiner radiobutton

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, updates

I would really appreciate a bit of advice on why my variable r is stuck at 1, yes I know i did set it to 1, however as I have investigated it should update once I click appropriate radio button. If I do not set r value to 1 it is always 0 in that case, and would really like to know how to update the button response on click.

```
def radio_button() -> int:
    print(r.get())
return r.get()

r = IntVar()
r.set(1)

Radiobutton(third_window, text="Lightly active", variable=r, value=1, command=radio_button).grid(
    row=4, column=0)
Radiobutton(third_window, text="Medium active", variable=r, value=2, command=radio_button).grid(
    row=4, column=1)
Radiobutton(third_window, text="Heavily active", variable=r, value=3, command=radio_button).grid(
    row=4, column=2)

def submit_button():
    result = int(weight_entry.get()) + int(height_entry.get()) + int(age_entry.get()) + radio_button()
    result_label = Label(third_window, text=str(result) + " Calories per day").grid(row=14, column=1)

btn_submit = tk.Button(third_window, text="Submit", command=submit_button, padx=30, pady=10)
btn_submit.grid(row=8, column=0)
```

Comment: Is this really your actual code? The `return` statement is not inside the `radio_button` function.

Comment: well it is only part of it, and due to somehow after copy/paste my function radio_button indentation got misplaced.

Comment: We need code that actually produces the behavior you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate the help however I have already solved it, i forgot to mention that this function which creates a whole new window is in another window, which meant that when i Declared the r = IntVar() I had to declare which root/master/window it should be in.
In my case it was r = IntVar(third_window)